# d3 word cloud - words out of bounds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 word cloud (https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) and I can't seem to keep the words within the boundaries. About every 3rd or 4th load it will cut off a word.

```
d3.layout.cloud()
        .size([800, 300])
        .words(words)
        .overflow(true)
        .rotate(0)
        .padding(6)
        .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .on("end", draw)
        .start();

function draw(words) {
    d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 300)
            .attr("class", "wordcloud")
            .append("g")
        // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
        // appear outside of the SVG area
            .attr("transform", "translate(370,155)")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("-webkit-text-stroke-width", "1px")
            .style("-webkit-text-stroke-color", "black")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
            .on("click", function (d, i){
             window.open(d.url, "_self");
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: This implementation doesn't have anything to enforce that everything stays within the provided size. You'll have to make the canvas bigger, font smaller or reduce the number of words.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your text-anchor attribute to start and using the Math.abs() on your d.x value within the translate method will help.

You'd be left with the below as your draw function:

```
function draw(words) {
d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 300)
        .attr("class", "wordcloud")
        .append("g")
    // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
    // appear outside of the SVG area
        .attr("transform", "translate(370,155)")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("-webkit-text-stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("-webkit-text-stroke-color", "black")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [Math.abs(d.x), d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
        .on("click", function (d, i){
         window.open(d.url, "_self");
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reduce the word font size, to ensure the words fit in the svg or increase the size of svg.